# Google Home Action is being throttled

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created a Google Home action that plays short audio clips in a sequence. Each clip about a couple of seconds long.

Flow is as below.

Play audio1.
MEDIA_STATUS intent is triggered at the end of audio1. Then play audio2
MEDIA_STATUS intent is triggered at the end of audio2. Then play audio3
Then Play audio4 and so on
Issue is that the execution pauses after every 4 or 5 audio clips are played. The pause varies between half a minute to even two minutes long.

- Seeing this problem in Google Home Speaker. Not seeing problem in Simulator (in browser)
- Based on the logs, there is no delay in the action between request received and response sent. The pause seems to be because agent is being called after a pause.

Probably the speaker takes a pause and does not call the backend for those durations?
What else could be causing this, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with old assistant library. Which on are you using? The new one is called assistant-conversation-nodejs. If you are using the old one then only thing you can do is to update, as the old one is not being updated.